# Force Xcode to build with specific .framework

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a target that links with a framework (both of which I develop). If I build the target it builds the framework before hand for use in the target.

What I want during certain builds is to bring in an existing already built version of that framework and use it during the build of that target. Is there a way to force xcode to build using an already compiled version of a dependant framework

(The reason I'm doing this is because I have multiple targets that are built separately and want them all to be built using the same framework binary)

Comment: So you always want to use a pre-built?

Comment: @MobileBen while developing I want to use the linked framework, but when i do my builds (jenkins) i want to be using a single version of the framework for all my builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this, this can be done by turning off the "Find Implicit Dependencies" under your build scheme.

[image]

Some good reading can be found here on the topic here: https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/managing_xcode.html#scheme-action